# How to read comment inside an array

Tags: php

Lets say I have this array:

```
$arr = [
    "UK" #United Kingdom
    ,"USA" #United States
    ,"BR" #Brazil
];
```

Is it possible to loop through the array AND a part from the value itself also get the comment?
Of course I could make this to a key/value array. But as there are so many entries I wonder if I can take advantage of the comments.

Basically I would need to do:

```
foreach($arr as $key=>value) {
    echo 'Code: ' . $key . PHP_EOL;
    echo 'Name: ' . $value . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Doing this today it is of course giving me the array index as key and the code as value.

Comment: You can use tokenizer https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php or reflection https://www.php.net/language.oop5.reflection to gather the comments from a php file. But in your case that would be a very bulky way of avoiding just turning your array in to a key=>value array. If you have a huge array just use your IDE's search/replace. Replace "#"  with "=> ' " etc. Or write a macro that will format your array. Then apply the answer from @Dokik below

Answer (score 4):

You need to define your array as following

```
$arr = [
"UK" => "United Kingdom",
"USA" => "United States of America",
"AT" => "Austria"
]
```

and so on. where anything on the left of the arrow is the key and anything to the right is the value.

Also, your foreach should be

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value){
...
}
```

Comment: Well I am aware of this. But as there are hundreds of entries I wondered if I could skip rewriting the array and use the comments as values.

Comment: Not that I am aware of. However I found this with a quick search https://www.html-code-generator.com/php/array/country-names If you scroll down a little you will find the array with the key value pairs of code and name